# Random forests and data imputation for both categorical and numerical data (mixed data). Have classification trees or regression trees been used?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

Using randomForest in R I have imputed missing values from a dataset of categorical and numerical variables. My query is regarding the following data imputation process  -

The initial forest is built using median imputation, proximities
are calculated, and new imputations are obtained by a proximity-weighted average
for a continuous predictor or a proximity-weighted vote for a categorical predictor.
A new forest is then built, giving new proximities and imputations. And then this is iterated five or six times for stable imputations.

Does the forest being built consist of classification trees or regression trees if the data is mixed? Or both?

Also when does bootstrapping come into this procedure?

I get out of bag MSE as output In R. I believe this means regression trees have been used. Is this correct?

Thank you